# question about a proof on Murphy's book about $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I'm reading Murphys book "C$^*$-algebras and operator theory" and I have a question about a proof in chapter 3.

The statement is (Theorem 3.1.8): Let I be a closed ideal in a C$^*$-algebra A. Then there is a unique $*$-homomorphism $\varphi:A\to M(I)$ extending the inclusion $i:I\to M(I)$. Moreover, $\varphi$ is injective if $I$ is essential in $A$.

Here is $M(I)$ the multiplier algebra of $I$ (which contains all double centralizers of $I$ and $\varphi:A\to M(I)$ is defined by $a\mapsto (L_a,R_a)$, where $L_a(x)=ax$ and $R_a(x)=xa$ for all $x\in A$.

My first question is about the uniqueness of $\varphi$: It starts with "Suppose that $\psi:A\to M(I)$ is another such extension of $i$. For all $a\in A$, $b\in I$ then $$\varphi(a)b=\varphi(ab)=ab=\psi(ab)=\psi(a)b".$$

I dont know, how to read $\varphi(a)b$ because $\varphi(a)=(L_a,R_a)\in L(A) \oplus L(A)$ ($L(A)$=bounded linear operator an $A$). And $b$ is only 
 in $I$. And why is it equal to $ab$?

My second question is how to use that $I$ is essential in $A$ if you prove the injectivity (later..)

Regards.

Comment: $\phi$ is an extension of the inclusion of $I$ into its multiplier algebra, hence $b = \phi(b)$ for any $b\in I$. Moreover $ab\in I$ since $b\in I$ and $I$ is an ideal of $A$, hence $\phi(ab)=ab$ for the same reason as before. Observe that $I$ is essential in $A$ if $aI=\{0\}$ implies $a=0$.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of the **multiplier** algebra is that you should be able to multiply. So $\varphi(a)b$ has to make sense. If you look at page 39 in Murphy's book, you see that the definition of $M(I)$ includes a canonical identification of $I$ as an ideal on $M(I)$.

As Phoenix mentioned, $\varphi$ extends the inclusion $I\to M(I)$. So $$\varphi(a)b=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)=\varphi(ab)=ab,$$ since $ab\in I$. Explicitly, $$\varphi(a)b=(L_a,R_a)(L_b,R_b)=(L_aL_b,R_aR_b)=(L_{ab},R_{ab})=\varphi(ab).$$

When $I$ is essential, if $a\in\ker\varphi$, then $\varphi(a)=0$ so $aI=0$; by definition of essential (above 3.1.8), $a=0$. So $\varphi$ is injective.